# Why isnt this objective-c IOS code leaking?

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsstring, instruments, memory-leaks

I am reusing surl so it seems like it would be leaking. But instruments does not show a link. I must not be understanding how it can reuse it without creating garbage strings.

```
NSString *rcode = @"DDD";

NSString *surl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.myweather.com/%@_%@.png", rcode, @"7"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: surl]; 
UIImage *image7 = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 

surl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.myweather.com/%@_%@.png", rrcode, @"6"];
url = [NSURL URLWithString: surl]; 
UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 

surl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.myweather.com/%@_%@.png", rrcode, @"5"];
url = [NSURL URLWithString: surl]; 
UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Comment: Doesn't ObjC have decent GC now?

Comment: @cHao Objective C for Mac OS X development can use GC. For iOS there is no GC. But with iOS 5 sdk they have added [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

`[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.myweather.com/%@_%@.png", rcode, @"7"];`

`+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is a "convenience constructor", sometimes called a "convenience method", that returns an NSString that you do not own, so you don't have any responsibility to release it unless you choose to retain it yourself (which you didn't).

The basic rule is if you get an object from a method that begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, then you have a responsibility to release it. Otherwise, you don't.

I don't see a leak here with or without ARC.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not leaking because it is using 'autoreleased' objects.

All the object creation code you have written is using convenience methods which return autoreleased objects. This means that these will be released when the corresponding autorelease pool will get released.

Please refer to this page in Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) to know more about autorelease.

Comment: Thank you for the link! And feedback!